# Unable to Resovle MySQL Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have one Master Table with Client_ID and other details of Client. The Second Table is a daily records tabel linked to master Table on Client_ID and has additional column for recording current date. Hence, the Client_ID in the second table has repetitie records based on each date.

I am trying to Select such Records with Client_ID From Master Table for Which Records of Current Date do not exist.

My attempted SQL Statement is as follows:-

```
SELECT  `Client_ID`, `Client_RFID_Number` 
FROM ciom_master AS a
WHERE  (`Client_Active` ='Y' OR `Client_Active` ='y')
 AND   CURDATE() NOT EXISTS (
                             SELECT (`Client_Check_Out`)
                             FROM `cio_master` AS b
                             WHERE a.Client_ID = b.Client_ID )
 AND   CURDATE() NOT EXISTS (
                             SELECT (`Client_Check_In`)
                             FROM `cio_master` AS c
                             WHERE a.Client_ID = c.Client_ID )
```

I am unable to resolve this statement error. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the `CURDATE()` inside the `NOT EXISTS` queries:

```
SELECT  `Client_ID`, `Client_RFID_Number` 
FROM ciom_master AS a
WHERE  (`Client_Active` ='Y' OR `Client_Active` ='y')
    AND NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT (`Client_Check_Out`)
                    FROM `cio_master` AS b
                    WHERE a.Client_ID = b.Client_ID 
                        and Client_Check_Out = CURDATE() )
 AND NOT EXISTS (
                 SELECT (`Client_Check_In`)
                 FROM `cio_master` AS c
                 WHERE a.Client_ID = c.Client_ID 
                     and Client_Check_In = CURDATE())
```

Comment: Oh Thanks... That was quick and really works. Thanks Again

Comment: @Rocky You're welcome. Please don't forget to upvote / mark answer as correct.

Comment: I am not sure If I have to create a new thread but please If you could tell me How Do I insert the result of this SQL into a Third Table through without duplicating the records in the Thrid Table if I repeat this SQL more than once.

Comment: Oops I am struck until lapse of next 90min

Comment: My New Thread is on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42934360/insert-records-in-a-table-without-duplicating-the-records